# Styling a voting system

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a sample voting system here: [Sample Voting System](http://ankursinha.net/polls/voting.php)

However after repeated attempts I couldn't get it to style the way I want because the developer has used way too many divs here. Either the font becomes too big or gets overlapped with the number or goes out of proportion, etc.

I want it to look something like this:

[image: Styling the Voting system]

And here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Sample Polling System</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".vote").click(function() 
{
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
var parent = $(this);
if(name=='up')
{
$(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="dot.gif" align="absmiddle">');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "up_vote.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
parent.html(html);
}  
}); 
}
else
{
$(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="dot.gif" align="absmiddle">');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "down_vote.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
parent.html(html);
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
body
{
font-family:'Georgia', Times New Roman, Times, serif;
}
#main
{
height:100px; 
width:800px;
}
a
{
color:#DF3D82;
text-decoration:none;

}
a:hover
{
color:#DF3D82;
text-decoration:underline;

}
.up
{
height:40px; font-size:24px; text-align:center; background-color:gray; margin-bottom:2px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}
.up a
{
color:#FFFFFF;
text-decoration:none;

}
.up a:hover
{
color:#FFFFFF;
text-decoration:none;

}
.down
{
height:40px; font-size:24px; text-align:center; background-color:gray; margin-top:2px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}

.down a
{
color:#FFFFFF;
text-decoration:none;

}
.down a:hover
{
color:#FFFFFF;
text-decoration:none;

}
.box1
{
float:left; height:80px; width:50px;
}
.box2
{
float:left; width:440px; text-align:left;
margin-left:10px;height:60px;margin-top:10px;
font-size:18px;
}
img
{
border:none;
padding-top:7px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<h3>Sample Polling System</h3><hr>
<?php
include('config.php');
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Messages  LIMIT 9");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$msg=$row['msg'];
$mes_id=$row['mes_id'];
$up=$row['up'];
$down=$row['down'];
?>
<div id="main">
<div class="box1">
<div class='up'><a href="" class="vote" id="<?php echo $mes_id; ?>" name="up"><?php echo $up; ?></a><!--Tried placing here, didn't work--></div>
<div class='down'><a href="" class="vote" id="<?php echo $mes_id; ?>" name="down"><?php echo $down; ?></a></div>
</div><!-- tried to put this box below box2 but still didn't work -->
<div class='box2' ><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
</div><!-- tried atleast 10 permutations and combinations, couldn't get it work-->
<hr>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me get the effect I want to achieve.

Thank You

Comment: What is the problem?  The only difference I see is that your options are side by side, where on the page, they are vertical.  Is that the only problem?

Comment: First of all: You have **multiple ids** in that page. Not cool. If you can do something (or make the developer do something) about it, then do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed your code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Sample Polling System</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".vote").click(function() 
{
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
var parent = $(this);
if(name=='up')
{
$(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="dot.gif" align="absmiddle">');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "up_vote.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
parent.html(html);
}  
}); 
}
else
{
$(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="dot.gif" align="absmiddle">');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "down_vote.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
parent.html(html);
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
body
{
font-family:'Georgia', Times New Roman, Times, serif;
}
#main
{
width:800px;
overflow:hidden;
}
a
{
color:#DF3D82;
text-decoration:none;

}
a:hover
{
color:#DF3D82;
text-decoration:underline;

}
.up
{
height:40px; font-size:24px; text-align:center; background-color:gray; margin-bottom:2px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;-webkit-border-radius: 6px; float:left; width:40px; 
}
.up a
{
color:#FFFFFF;
text-decoration:none;

}
.up a:hover
{
color:#FFFFFF;
text-decoration:none;

}
.down
{
height:40px; font-size:24px; text-align:center; background-color:gray; margin-top:2px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;-webkit-border-radius: 6px; float:left; margin-left:40px; width:40px; 
}

.down a
{
color:#FFFFFF;
text-decoration:none;

}
.down a:hover
{
color:#FFFFFF;
text-decoration:none;

}
.box1
{
float:left; clear:both;
}
.box2
{
float:left; width:440px;  text-align:left;
font-size:18px; 
}
img
{
border:none;
padding-top:7px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<h3>Sample Polling System</h3><hr>
<?php
include('config.php');
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Messages  LIMIT 9");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$msg=$row['msg'];
$mes_id=$row['mes_id'];
$up=$row['up'];
$down=$row['down'];
?>
<div id="main">
<div class='box2' ><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
<div class="box1">
<div class='up'><a href="" class="vote" id="<?php echo $mes_id; ?>" name="up"><?php echo $up; ?></a></div><span style="margin-top:10px; float:left; margin-left:10px;">People Agree to This</span>
<div class='down'><a href="" class="vote" id="<?php echo $mes_id; ?>" name="down"><?php echo $down; ?></a></div><span style=" margin-top:10px; float:left; margin-left:10px;">People Disagree to This</span>
</div><!-- tried to put this box below box2 but still didn't work -->

</div><!-- tried atleast 10 permutations and combinations, couldn't get it work-->
<hr>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/qCwZd/

`#box2` which is the title was placed above `#box1`, I gave it a `float:left;` and `#box1` got a `float:left;` and a `clear:both;` so it can show up on a new line.

I added a `span` beside every gray box, the first says **People agree to this**, the other **People disagree to this**, they were given a `float:left;` to lay beside the gray boxes, and some `margin-left`. I removed some `height` properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code. But plenty thanks for the explanation below. I messed around with your explanation and succeeded getting what I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

First you should have your markup also changed. You are using multiple elemtn ID's with the same name ('main') which is wrong. You should not have more than 1 element width the same ID in one HTML page.

Instead of your markup I suggest you to do the following:

```
<div align="center">
<h3>Sample Polling System</h3><hr>
<div id="main">

 <div class="row">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="item">
    <div class="box1">
     <div class='up'><a href="" class="vote" id="13" name="up">2</a></div>
     <div class='down'><a href="" class="vote" id="13" name="down">0</a></div>
    </div><!--end box1-->
    <div class='box2' >Sachin Tendulkar is GOD</div>
   </div><!--end item-->

  <div class="item">
    <div class="box1">
     <div class='up'><a href="" class="vote" id="13" name="up">2</a></div>
     <div class='down'><a href="" class="vote" id="13" name="down">0</a></div>
    </div><!--end box1-->
    <div class='box2' >Sachin Tendulkar is GOD</div>
   </div><!--end item-->
 </div><!--end wrapper-->
</div><!--end row-->

</div><!--end main-->
```

and then your css can simply be:

```
#main{width:100%;}
.row{width:100%; border-bottom:1px solid black;}
.wrapper{width:800px; margin:0 auto;}
.item{width:400px; float:left;}
```

you can see a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/gHmDv/

Answer (score 0):

I have made a voting system here. I have taken the colors from the votes of Stackoverflow. I have made the "icons" with clip-path and have given them a triangle shape. With the radio buttons I have connected the labels with the name property and if you now click the triangle then the radio button is activated and the triangle turns orange. Here is the code (you can leave out the javascript code):

```js
var number = 0;
var count = document.getElementById("voteCounter");

function plusOne() {
  number = 1;
  count.innerHTML = number;
}

function minusOne() {
  number = - 1;
  count.innerHTML = number;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#vote {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #6C737B;
}

#upvote {
  background: #BCC0C3;
  height: 50px;
  width: 40px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 60%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#downvote {
  background: #BCC0C3;
  height: 50px;
  width: 40px;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 40%, 100% 0%, 0% 0%);
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[id="upvoteRadio"]:checked ~ #upvote {
  background: #E5863D;
}

input[id="downvoteRadio"]:checked ~ #downvote {
  background: #E5863D;
}
```

```html
<div id="vote">
  <input type="radio" id="upvoteRadio" name="vote" value="upvote">
  <label for="upvoteRadio" id="upvote" onclick="plusOne()"></label>
  <p id="voteCounter">0</p>
  <input type="radio" id="downvoteRadio" name="vote">
  <label for="downvoteRadio" id="downvote" onclick="minusOne()"></label>
</div>
```